# Притяжение частиц

Tags: разработка-игр, java, физика

Делаю игру. В ней должны непрерывно высчитываться координаты частиц, притягивающихся между собой по закону всемирного тяготения. 
Расчёты у меня производятся по формуле:

```
F=G*m1*m2/(d*d);
```

Где G - некоторая константа, m1, m2 - массы частиц, а d - расстояние между частицами.

Расчёты  производятся попарно между каждыми двумя частицами. В итоге имеем n! расчётов за один раз, что не есть хорошо. И при n>700 приложение начинает всё больше и больше тормозить.

Теперь вопрос. Как можно упростить/оптимизировать эти вычисления? Может быть, предложите использовать какие-либо библиотеки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, стоит попытаться ограничить радиус взаимодействия частиц. Сила обратно пропорциональна квадрату расстояния, значит, с ростом расстояния быстро убывает. Можно подобрать такое предельное расстояние, на котором сила взаимодействия частиц незначительна и может быть приравняна к нулю. Если предельная физическая достоверность симуляции не является приоритетом, это поможет снизить число вычислений.

Во-вторых, для ускорения поиска частиц, входящих в радиус взаимодействия, можно хранить их не в виде списка, а в [BSP-дереве](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) (BSP - Binary Space Partition, двоичное разбиение пространства).

В-третьих (в последнюю очередь!), можно заняться микрооптимизациями. Например, расстояние вы наверняка вычисляете как корень из суммы квадратов разностей координат частиц (`sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)`). А при вычислении силы вы это же значение возводите в квадрат. Можно избежать вычисления корня и квадрата, если в формулу вычисления силы взаимодействия частиц сразу подставлять сумму квадратов разностей координат.

Вообще, профайлер вам в руки, прогоняйте ваш код, смотрите, какой его участок сильнее всего грузит процессор и оптимизируйте его в первую очередь.

Comment: Почему микрооптимизациями нужно заниматься в последнюю очередь?

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, главную роль играет способ решения(алгоритм) который вы используете. Микрооптимизации применяются к готовому алгоритму и как правило дают совсем незначительный прирост, если вообще его дают.